# Wordpress: add_action is never called

Tags: php, wordpress

The below code doesn't add the files to the header, and doesn't echo - so it's never called. Would love to know why.

```
    function image_cycle_script(){ 
    //Load the required script for the image cycler
    wp_register_script( 'cycle', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.cycle.lite.js', array( 'jquery' ) ); 
    wp_enqueue_script('cycle');
    echo 'LOCATION:'.get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.cycle.lite.js';
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'image_cycle_script' );
```

Comment: No need for this line:  echo 'LOCATION:'.get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.cycle.lite.js';

Comment: Obviously, but it's there to tell me if the function is being called.

Comment: funcation is being called, and script is added in <head>

Comment: Did you insert the [wp_head()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_head) template tag in your `header.php` theme's file ?